# Applying a function to many lists

Tags: python

So I have several databases that I need to connect to at the very top of the code:

```
connections = [
    {
    'username': 'user',
    'password': 'pass',
    'host': 'host123',
    'database': 'db_dbs12',
    'table': 'table14',
    'schema': 'schema',
    'column': 'column1'
    },
    {
    'username': 'user',
    'password': 'pass',
    'host': 'host123',
    'database': 'db_dbs',
    'table': 'table1',
    'schema': 'schema',
    'column': 'column2'
    },
    {
    'username': 'user',
    'password': 'pass',
    'host': 'host1234',
    'database': 'db_dbs',
    'table': 'table1234',
    'schema': 'schema',
    'column': 'column3'
    },

]
```

And I am using the following query to connect using sqlalchemy:

```
def database():
    result = []
    
for details in connections:
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://' + details['username'] + ':' + details['password'] + '@' + details['host'] + '/' + details['database'] + '?charset=utf8') 
    query = ....

  .....   print(this) 
        print(test) 
        print('testing:', value, 'complete.')
```

At the end of the code I have some SQL queries calculating some data. I want connect to multiple databases and execute the same code every time, but have result for each database/connection shown above. I tried the 'for loop details in connection method', but it is just printing nothing at all.  How can I apply this function so it connects to each connection and shows the result for each?

Answer (score 0):

You could append the result from each query to a list to retrieve it after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Crete a list of the engines you connect to, and then run the query against each connected engine:

```py
engines = []
for details in connections:
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://' + details['username'] + ':' + details['password'] + '@' + details['host'] + '/' + details['database'] + '?charset=utf8') 
    # don't query here
    engines.append(engine)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```py
engines = [create_engine('mssql+pymssql://' + details['username'] + ':' + details['password'] + '@' + details['host'] + '/' + details['database'] + '?charset=utf8')
           for details in connections]
```

Then create a generic `query_all()` function which runs each query with all engines:

```py
def query_all(query, engines):
    results = []
    for engine in engines:
        query = engine.cursor.execute...  #
        for row in query.results():  # or fetch_all(), etc.
            results.append(row)
    return results


# use the function to get all results:
all_results = query_all("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students", engines)
more_results = query_all("SELECT student_id, grade FROM subjects", engines)
# etc.
```

Comment: thank you, but what goes after engine.cursor.execute... #?

Comment: Whatever you currently have in your `query = ....` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) function.

```py
results = list(map(database, connections))
```